# Gitlab-ci job of sonar-scan always succeeds irrespective of quality gate failure

Tags: sonarqube, gitlab, gitlab-ci, sonar-runner

I am using [tanlab's](http://www.talanlabs.com/) gitlab plugin for sonar reporting. Below is command I'm running it on gitlab ci pipeline:

```
sonar-scanner -Dproject.settings=sonar-project.properties -Dsonar.host.url=$HOST -Dsonar.login=$TOKEN -Dsonar.projectKey=$SONAR_PROJECT_KEY -Dsonar.projectName=$PROJECT_NAME -Dsonar.branch.name=$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME -Dsonar.gitlab.failure_notification_mode="exit-code" -Dsonar.qualitygate.wait=true -Dsonar.gitlab.query_wait=2000 -Dsonar.gitlab.query_max_retry=100 -Dsonar.analysis.mode=publish -Dsonar.gitlab.commit_sha="$CI_COMMIT_SHA" -Dsonar.gitlab.ref_name="$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME" -Dsonar.gitlab.project_id="$CI_PROJECT_PATH" -Dsonar.gitlab.disable_inline_comments=true
```

And here is the job output which is showing execution success, but the quality gate is failed with a critical bug.

```
...
 INFO: Analysis report generated in 1588ms, dir size=1 MB
 INFO: Analysis report compressed in 341ms, zip size=563 KB
 INFO: Analysis report uploaded in 298ms
 INFO: ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse https://xyz/dashboard?id=xyz&branch=xyz&resolved=false
 INFO: Note that you will be able to access the updated dashboard once the server has processed the submitted analysis report
 INFO: More about the report processing at ...
 INFO: Read data from file
 INFO: Save data from file
 INFO: Summary is saved under /builds/.../SummaryOfProjectAnalysis.json
 INFO: Executing post-job 'Summary of project analysis'
 INFO: PostJobContext is execute
 INFO: Save data from file
 INFO: Summary is saved under /builds/...
 INFO: Analysis total time: 48.293 s
 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 INFO: EXECUTION SUCCESS
 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 INFO: Total time: 1:51.196s
 INFO: Final Memory: 36M/475M
 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [07:36:13] SonarQube analysis finished.
```

Is there anything am I missing?

Comment: What version and license of SonarQube are you using?  AFAIK  `qualitygate.wait` option available only 8.1 and higher and only in Developer Edition

Comment: I am facing the same issue. How did you solve this one?